# Trouble adding an application xib/ nib file for swift in Xcode 7.0.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

When I click new file and go to user interface tab, I don't see the application or window options. The application file description should say "An Interface Builder document suitable for creating an iOS application, including an application delegate and window." I tried searching in the search bar in Xcode but application did not show up for iOS.

Please see screen shots and difference for clarity.

[app delegate screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tic3.png)

[my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m24Ml.png)

Comment: It hasn't looked like that in years. You are using an old, long-outdated tutorial of some kind, that's all.

Comment: @matt Which screenshot it outdated? Also, if the application option to create a new application nib file isn't shown on mine how do I create that new application nib file? My Xcode says it it the newest 7.0.1 version as well.

Comment: "What it should look like in Xcode" is outdated. That is not how it looks in Xcode and it hasn't looked that way in years. Just pick a template. Of course if the tutorial depends upon the application template you should also stop reading that tutorial, as you will not be able to do any of what it says.

Comment: @matt Thanks. I have choose an empty file and added a window and object but I am trying to add the app delegate to this as seen in the above new screenshots. How do I add or connect to the app delegate to get my screen to look like screenshot 2?

Comment: You're not listening to me. Everything you're trying to do is wrong. NONE of this works like your screen shots any more. Do I make myself perfectly clear? Drop this tutorial, whatever it is, and start again with something that is up to date. Drop it now. Now. And please delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple introduced storyboards back in 2011. Before that, developers used a .xib file to specify their user interfaces, and the "main" .xib file, i.e. the first one that the app loaded, included a proxy for the app delegate so that it was easy to connect objects to outlets in the app delegate. As matt has indicated, though, things haven't really worked that way for a while. As he says, it sounds like you're working from an old book or online tutorial, and as a result your expectations don't match the reality of modern iOS development.

These days, apps generally use a storyboard to specify all or part of the user interface. A big problem with .xib files was that you had to load an entire file at once; if you instantiated a view controller with `-initWithNibName:bundle:`, the entire file was loaded. That meant that you could only specify a single view controller in a given .xib file, and managing the relationships between view controllers was harder than it should be. Storyboards address this problem -- a single storyboard typically contains several view controllers.

I agree with matt that you really shouldn't work from material so old that it expects you to use .xib files to build your application. That story again:

## STOP USING THAT INFORMATION

There are plenty of great resources (notably matt's own [iOS 9 Programming Fundamentals with Swift](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920044345.do)) that will teach you how to write modern iOS code. [Apple's own documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214) is a great place to start.